# unable to install python from source

Tags: python, python-2.7

Every time I try to install install python 2.7.12 from source I get error while running the command `sudo make install` and python installation fails. However there is no error while running `make`. What could be the probable error?

```
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/__init__.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/expat.py ...
Listing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/__init__.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/_exceptions.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/handler.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/saxutils.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmllib.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

Comment: Depends on the error. Since you didn't provide the specific error it's impossible to tell.

Comment: My apologies ,added the message I m getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell since the error is so vague.  I would try running the configure file again with possible options about you system.  Without much more information, I can only guess you Makefile isn't configured right.

You can also try downloading it using apt-get with the deadsnake repository.  Just try:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7
apt-get update
apt-get install python2.7
```

[This link](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7) shows that it should give you python 2.7.12

Comment: indeed it is vague i too have been trying to search the cause of error

Comment: Just FYI, That repo is no longer maintained.